# UX design document for Web platform Grid control

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, grid

Is there any User experience(UX) design guideline document available for Web platform grid control? I am developing ASP.NET grid control and wanted to know if there is anything already available. I searched it in google and this Stackoverflow site, I couldnt find it.

Comment: Are you referring to guidelines for *any* web-based data grid? Is there something you're looking for in particular?

Comment: I need it especially for Microsoft related web related controls such as ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, or kind of. Microsoft (MSDN) have released [Walkthrough: Accessibility Guidelines for Using the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712726%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - which is a part of User Experience.

> This walkthrough shows how to use the GridView control in ways that help make a Web page accessible for people who use screen reader software. These techniques can help you meet the following Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 guideline: Separating structure from presentation (WCAG guideline 1.3).

If not comprehensive - it's a good start.

Comment: @sankar You're welcome. It took a while to find it :-)